# Gap around plumbing in bathroom floor/subfloor

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

We've just put a lot of effort into overhauling our 3rd floor (1890's frame house) including a bathroom. Our carpenter/handyman and plumber thought it was a good idea to leave a lot of clearance in the floor around the claw foot bathtub's plumbing, to give the pipes some play.

I don't like it - especially the gap extending from the cold supply all the way around the drain [image: see Pic1]

I certainly don't want to wait and see if mice will come through. The handyman's attitude is escutcheons cover all. Is that reasonable? If not, what are my best options for a fix - before the tub goes in.

Comment: I'd call that laziness. The tile should've been cut to fit, mosaic or not. Pipes don't need "play" of more than 1/32" so they don't squeak or click with elongation due to temperature changes.

Answer (score 4):

Escutcheons do cover the rough edges around a pipe penetration. But you'll never find an escutcheon that covers the combination of cold pipe and drain pipe. It'll take two, and they may or may not overlap each other well enough to fully cover the rough edges. IMHO this is sub-par workmanship; the tile guy just didn't want to take the time to trim four hexagons to fit neatly (but not necessarily snugly - you'd still need an escutcheon) around the two water pipes and that many again around the drain pipe.

At this point what's done is done, though; modifying the tile could be difficult. It'll require grinding or chipping out some grout and placing a few little tiles. Building support for those tiles in the chasm between the cold water and drain pipes could be tricky. It'll take some creativity and determination to get it done. It might involve fitting some wood backing below the subfloor, or possibly a bit of sheet metal on top of the subfloor.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at this high-end installation then you'll see that they seem to have used an entire tile as a sub-escutcheon below the metal escutcheon.

Not sure how this would play out for you since you have such small tiles.

[image]